# Task-based idle detection

Tags: c#, timer, async-await

It's not unusual to want a limit on the interval between certain events, and take action if the limit is exceeded.  For example, a heartbeat message between network peers for detecting that the other end is alive.

In the C# async/await style, it is possible to implement that by replacing the timeout task each time the heartbeat arrives:

```
var client = new TcpClient { ... };
await client.ConnectAsync(...);

Task heartbeatLost = new Task.Delay(HEARTBEAT_LOST_THRESHOLD);
while (...)
{
    Task<int> readTask = client.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Task first = await Task.WhenAny(heartbeatLost, readTask);
    if (first == readTask) {
        if (ProcessData(buffer, 0, readTask.Result).HeartbeatFound) {
            heartbeatLost = new Task.Delay(HEARTBEAT_LOST_THRESHOLD);
        }
    }
    else if (first == heartbeatLost) {
        TellUserPeerIsDown();
        break;
    }
}
```

This is convenient, but each instance of the delay `Task` owns a `Timer`, and if many heartbeat packets arrive in less time than the threshold, that's a lot of `Timer` objects loading the threadpool.  Also, the completion of each `Timer` will run code on the threadpool, whether there's any continuation still linked to it or not.

You can't free the old `Timer` by calling `heartbeatLost.Dispose()`; that'll give an exception

> `InvalidOperationException`: A task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state

One could create a `CancellationTokenSource` and use it to cancel the old delay task, but it seems suboptimal to create even more objects to accomplish this, when timers themselves have the feature of being reschedulable.

What's the best way to integrate timer rescheduling, so that the code could be structured more like this?

```
var client = new TcpClient { ... };
await client.ConnectAsync(...);

var idleTimeout = new TaskDelayedCompletionSource(HEARTBEAT_LOST_THRESHOLD);
Task heartbeatLost = idleTimeout.Task;
while (...)
{
    Task<int> readTask = client.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Task first = await Task.WhenAny(heartbeatLost, readTask);
    if (first == readTask) {
        if (ProcessData(buffer, 0, readTask.Result).HeartbeatFound) {
            idleTimeout.ResetDelay(HEARTBEAT_LOST_THRESHOLD);
        }
    }
    else if (first == heartbeatLost) {
        TellUserPeerIsDown();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the heartbeat failed during a read would the read not also have failed? if you do need a manual heart beat could that not be separate from your read, e.g. in another health monitoring loop that can send a cancel request to your read operation?

Comment: On second read of the desired version of your code, the "heartbeat" is being used to timeout the read. Could you not create a new timeout task for each read, or set the timeout on the connection directly?

Comment: Would you be willing to move `Task heartbeatLost = idleTimeout.Task;` inside of the `while (...)` loop? with it outside of the loop the problem is a lot harder to solve without race conditions.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Yeah, I was supposing that the delay can't be reset after it fires, but if a race condition exists then fetching the Task again is perfectly ok.

Comment: The race condition is if `heartbeatLost` transistions to the `Completed` state after the `WhenAny` call but before the `ResetDelay` you are screwed because you can't move a task out of the Completed state once you enter it. You must generate new Task objects for each loop.

Comment: @JSteward: If there were a "health monitoring loop", it would run into the same problem.  Most links (network, serial, etc) don't cause a read to fail if the source end locks up.  With a timeout on the read, the read would fail if the source end totally stops sending, but if it gets stuck sending bad or wrong messages repeatedly, it'll never time out.

Comment: @Scott: It's ok if `ResetDelay` can fail when the timeout triggered previously.  That basically means that the heartbeat arrived right *at* the threshold, and saying it was too late is just as valid as saying it's on time.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I like the answer you have, but couldn't `ResetDelay` be simplified to just a single `Timer.Change(newDelay, Infinite)` call?

Comment: No, because `ResetDelay` could be called on one thread while a 2nd thread is processing `OnTimerCallback`. Once your `TaskCompletionSource` has had any of the `TrySetXxxxx` methods called on any of it you can't change its state anymore and must make a new one.

Comment: @Scott: But then the threshold was exceeded, so it's ok to trigger the timeout response logic even if a heartbeat got processed after the timeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward to me, The name of your hypothetical class gets you most of the way there. All you need is a `TaskCompletionSource` and a single timer you keep resetting.

```
public class TaskDelayedCompletionSource
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _completionSource;
    private readonly System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    private readonly object _lockObject = new object();

    public TaskDelayedCompletionSource(int interval)
    {
        _completionSource = CreateCompletionSource();
        _timer = new Timer(OnTimerCallback);
        _timer.Change(interval, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private static TaskCompletionSource<bool> CreateCompletionSource()
    {
        return new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach | TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously | TaskCreationOptions.HideScheduler);
    }

    private void OnTimerCallback(object state)
    {
        //Cache a copy of the completion source before we entier the lock, so we don't complete the wrong source if ResetDelay is in the middle of being called.
        var completionSource = _completionSource;
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            completionSource.TrySetResult(true);
        }
    }

    public void ResetDelay(int interval)
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            var oldSource = _completionSource;
            _timer.Change(interval, Timeout.Infinite);
            _completionSource = CreateCompletionSource();
            oldSource.TrySetCanceled();
        }
    }
    public Task Task => _completionSource.Task;
}
```

This will only create a single timer and update it, the task completes when the timer fires.

You will need to change your code slightly, because a new TaskCompletionSource gets created every time you update the end time you need to put the `Task heartbeatLost = idleTimeout.Task;` call inside the while loop.

```
var client = new TcpClient { ... };
await client.ConnectAsync(...);

var idleTimeout = new TaskDelayedCompletionSource(HEARTBEAT_LOST_THRESHOLD);
while (...)
{
    Task heartbeatLost = idleTimeout.Task;
    Task<int> readTask = client.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Task first = await Task.WhenAny(heartbeatLost, readTask);
    if (first == readTask) {
        if (ProcessData(buffer, 0, readTask.Result).HeartbeatFound) {
            idleTimeout.ResetDelay(HEARTBEAT_LOST_THRESHOLD);
        }
    }
    else if (first == heartbeatLost) {
        TellUserPeerIsDown();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** If you where conserened about the object creation of the completion sources (for example you are programming in a Game Engine where GC collection is a large consern) you may be able to add extra logic to `OnTimerCallback` and `ResetDelay` to reuse the completion source if the call has not happened yet and you know for sure you are not inside of a Reset Delay.

You will likely need to switch from using a `lock` to a `SemaphoreSlim` and change the callback to

```
    private void OnTimerCallback(object state)
    {
        if(_semaphore.Wait(0))
        {
            _completionSource.TrySetResult(true);
        }
    }
```

I may update this answer later to include what `OnTimerCallback` would have too, but I don't have time right now.

Comment: I just edited the use case in the question to do `break;` when the timeout happens, to make it clear it doesn't matter what happens with the timer after that.

Comment: BTW this turned out nice and straightforward.  I was a bit hesitant to recreate the "Task around a Timer" after seeing how complicated the BCL version was, with TimerPromise helper class and so forth.